# Left Side Bar Responsive Issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
  <script>

     function toggleSidebar()
     {
       document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";

      }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default cs-navabar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img  class="left-logo" src="lefttoplogo.svg">
            <h6 class="emotext"><u>login</u></h6> <img  class="right" src="rtlogotop.svg">
                <p class="logout-text"><u>LOGOUT</u></p> 
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div id= "sidebar">
      <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>

      </div>

      <img class="adminlogo" src="admin.svg">
       <ul>
       <img src="Untitled-3.svg">
        <li>Add </li>
        <li>View</li>
        <li>App</li>
        <li>Add</li>
        <li>SMS  </li>
        <li>Edit</li>
        <li>SMS</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Above is the code snippet for left sidebar, i am facing issues regarding responsiveness for mobiles with the side bar, it doesn't hide when the screen width is reduced. Please if any one can help with the above issue?

Comment: Why are you using js and not media queries to do that?

Comment: @MattiaAstorino side bar should hide and  become a clickable hamburger menu when width is reduced to 480px and below that is the reason i why  have used JS.

Comment: Atul You wrote id= "sidebar". Try to remove the space.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function with `window.width`, so whenever the width is less than 480 you can target the element which you want to hide. Something like this:

```
function navigation() {
  if (window.width <= 480) {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could embed some code example, so we can see what you mean?

Comment: function navigation() {
  if (window.width <= 480) {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide it use:

```
@media(max-width: 420px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```